# STD: out of range memory location

Tags: c++, structure

I have written a program to read a .csv file and store the information into a structure for that purpose. I have made an array of structure and I am storing the information in it, when I try to run the program, it keeps on giving me out of range memory location exception. Where can the problem be?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "structure.h"

using namespace std;

void main () {
    burgerking *burger;
    burger = new burgerking[7000];
    string line;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("burgerking.csv"); //opening the csv file
    if(myfile.good())
        cout<<"File is Good to be opened"<<endl;
    int i=0;
    int l=0;   //longitude
    int n=1;   //latutude
    int e=2;   //location
    int ss=3;  //state
    int ad=4;  //address
    int j=0;
    int b=0;
    int kk=0;
    int ll=0;
    int add=0;
    string line1;
    string line2;
    string line3;
    while(!myfile.eof())
    {
        cout<<i;
        getline(myfile,line,',');
        if(i==0)
        {
            burger[j].longitude=line;
            j++;
            l=l+7;
        }
        if(i==l)
        {
            burger[j].longitude=line.substr(16,line.length());
            j++;
            l=l+7;
        }
        if(i==n)
        {
            burger[b].latitude=line;
            n=n+7;
            b++;
        }
        if(e==i)
        {
            burger[kk].location=line;
            kk=kk+1;
            e=e+7;
        }
        if(ss==i)
        {
            burger[ll].state=line;
            ss=ss+7;
            ll++;
        }
        i++;

    }
    myfile.close();
    myfile.open("burgerking.csv");
    int c=0;
    while(!myfile.eof())
    {
        getline(myfile,line,',');
        if(ad==c)
        {

            getline(myfile,line1,',');
            getline(myfile,line2,',');
            getline(myfile,line3,',');
            line3=line3.substr(0,16);
            burger[add].address=line+','+line1+','+line2+','+line3;
            add++;
            ad=ad+4;

        }
        c++;
    }

    ofstream outputfile;
    outputfile.open("output.txt");
    if(outputfile.is_open())
    {
    for(int k=0;k<300;k++)// loop just to check the program output
    {
        outputfile<<'\t'<<'\t'<<k+1<<endl;
        outputfile<<burger[k].longitude<<'\t';
        outputfile<<burger[k].latitude<<'\t';
        outputfile<<burger[k].location<<'\t';
        outputfile<<burger[k].state<<endl<<'\t';
        outputfile<<burger[k].address<<endl<<endl<<endl; //just to check the output 
    }
    }


    outputfile.close();
    myfile.close();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: You should have debugged the code and locate the exact location of the error. Moreover, your variable names should mean something to another reader. Instead of commenting them, why don't you just use comments as variable names?

Comment: Why have an if statement when things are good but do nowt when things are bad?

Answer (score 1):

Your csv reading logic is extraordinarily complicated. You should read a line at a time and parse fields out separately. This will spare you a huge amount of pain:

```
std::vector<burgerking> burger;
std::string line;
bool first = true;
while (getline(myfile, line)) {
    std::ostringstream fields(line);

    burgerking b;
    getline(fields, b.longitude, ',');
    getline(fields, b.latitude , ',');
    getline(fields, b.location , ',');
    getline(fields, b.state    , ',');

    std::string addr1, addr2, addr3, addr3;
    getline(fields, b.addr1, ',');
    getline(fields, b.addr2, ',');
    getline(fields, b.addr3, ',');
    getline(fields, b.addr4, ',');
    b.address = addr1 + ',' + addr2 + ',' + addr3 + ',' + addr4.substr(0, 16);

    if (!first)
      b.longitude = b.longitude.substr(16);
    first = false;

    burger.push_back(b); // emplace_back() if you're using C++11.
}
```

There's some weirdness in your logic: you skip in increments of 7, but there appear to be eight fields (lng, lat, loc, state and four address lines). I don't know whether I've misread your logic or you have a bug, so you may have to adjust the above code to correct for any misunderstandings.

I can't say for sure if the current iteration logic is the reason for your problem (it's too much effort to tease apart the gazillion variables you've used, especially without access to a sample of the csv file itself), but it probably is, and you should change it even if it isn't.